Is "emblem" used with something trivial?
I always think of an "emblem" as something traditional and representing a nation and the like. So, I'm wondering if, for example, the following sentence is correct:

The car is an emblem of wealth in developing countries.

If not, what word should I use?

Can you explain your intended meaning a bit? Are you saying that one way that rich people show off their wealth is by buying a car? Are you saying that when non-rich people imagine being rich, a major thing they picture is having a car? Are you saying that if filmmakers want to show that someone is rich, they'll show them in a car? Something else?

Not really. It's not totally about showing off. I mean there might be people who show off that way, but mostly it's just that when you look at somebody who owns a car, you think they are kind of rich. This idea is a bit out-dated but it was true a decade or two ago.

"symbol"  might be an alternative.  Eg "status symbol"Read https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1369847817302930

In my city there is a chain of fried-chicken shops whose emblem is a cartoon cockerel.wesring a chef's hat.It is seen on shop signage, carry-out boxes, paper napkins, staff uniforms, etc. Is that trivial enough?

Yes, I always thought of an emblem as something suggestive of a country, like America’s national emblem is the bald eagle.

So turns out it's not necessarily something formal. So, is it used correctly in my example?


[…] it's just that when you look at somebody who owns a car, you think they are kind of rich.

Personally, I wouldn't use "emblem" in that situation; to me "emblem" implies not just that something is perceived as representing something, but that it's used to represent that thing. (I note that several of Merriam-Webster's definitions specifically mention how the emblem is intended or used.) Now, if something is an emblem of wealth, that doesn't necessarily mean that wealthy people themselves choose to use it that way — it could be that writers, filmmakers, artists, etc., use it as a shorthand for wealth — but I wouldn't use "emblem" unless someone is selecting it to represent wealth.
Rather, I would usually use "sign" for this.
To say that people assume car owners are generally rich, you can write:

The car is seen as a sign of wealth in developing countries.

If you're OK with directly suggesting that car owners are generally rich (rather than imputing that to other people's interpretations), then you can shorten that to:

The car is a sign of wealth in developing countries.


Nice! What about "status symbol" as James suggested? I find it also pretty suitable here.

@anIELTSlearner: Unfortunately not: the term "status symbol" is more broad, encompassing not only symbols of wealth but also symbols of other forms of power or prestige. So while it's completely fine (and may be accurate) to say "The car is a status symbol in developing countries", that doesn't capture the meaning that you've said you're going for.

I think I misread James's comment. It should have been if "The car is a symbol of wealth in developing countries." is correct. Does your answer change?

@anIELTSlearner: I would be fine with "a symbol of wealth", but as I've written here, I would usually use "sign".

Yes, I'll keep that in mind too.

"Emblem" simply means a badge or symbol, usually with positive connotation. Your usage is correct.

The UL emblem shows the product was tested.
The emblem of Papua New Guinea shows a bird-of-paradise, spear and drum.

